# amChart displays on pc, but doesn't render on mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile, charts, responsive-design, amcharts

I have a simple XY Chart that works as expected when I view it on PC, but when I try to view it on my phone it just shows blank white space. I've been looking at the amChart docs and I enabled the responsive plugin, but this had no effect. I've tested it in mobile chrome/safari and the result is the same. What am I doing wrong? If you visit https://tempguard-4cdcc.web.app/dashboard.html and then navigate to History you will find the chart. (landing on dashboard.html starts the temperature simulation that feeds the data series in the charts in the History page).

```
// am4core code - builds chart
function makeChart(sensorID) {
  // Pulling data from selected sensor
  // eslint-disable-next-line object-curly-spacing
  const { tempRecords } = sensorListData[sensorID];

  // Create chart instance
  let chart = am4core.create('chartdiv', am4charts.XYChart);

  // Add data
  // chart.data = generateChartData();
  chart.data = tempRecords;

  // Create axes
  let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
  dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;
  dateAxis.title.text = 'Date';
  dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey('MMM dd hh:mm:ss a');

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  // Create series
  let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = 'temp';
  series.dataFields.dateX = 'date';
  series.strokeWidth = 2;
  series.minBulletDistance = 10;
  series.tooltipText = '{valueY}';
  series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = 'vertical';
  series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 20;
  series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;
  series.tooltip.label.padding(12, 12, 12, 12);

  // Adding yAxis Title
  valueAxis.title.text = 'Temperature';

  // Add scrollbar
  chart.scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
  chart.scrollbarX.series.push(series);

  // Add cursor
  chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
  chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
  chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;

  // Add responsive plugin
  chart.responsive.enabled = true;
}
```

[image: mobile view showing axes but no chart body]

Comment: Same Here. Could you solve it?